# Anylogic Fluid Process Tank, how to interrupt processing?

Tags: interrupt, fluid, anylogic

I have product filling a tank.  When we stop filling, the tank needs to settle for a certain amount of time (solid particles to settle out, calm to return to take a measurement, certify the product) then the content is released.  Settling time depends on product, but let's say it is 24 hours.  I use a processTank for this in Anylogic.  Easy when the tank is filled to capacity.  Sometimes though the tank is not filled to capacity - in this case we can kick of "settling" by calling `processTank.forceProcessing()`.  Works fine.

However now have a situation where the tank is in the process of settling (processing has started), more product has arrived and it needs to go somewhere, the only place is the tank being processed.  The "new arrival of fluid" should interrupt the settling (processing) until the tank is either filled to capacity, or until the inflow of product stops, where after processing can follow from scratch.

Q:  How do you interrupt the processing in the tank.  There is no function to "interrupt" or "stop" processing.  Changing the DelayTime while processing does nothing.  Thus `processTank.set_DelayTime(x)` sets a new delaytime, but the current processing first completes at the old delay time before it updates the value.  (yes I checked the time remaining before changing the delay time while it was processing).  If there is a different way to achieve same operation please feel free to suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't interrupt the delay.

For these specific customized functionalities, I would suggest to use a normal tank instead of a process tank... at the end of the day a process tank can be represented easily by a tank with 2 valves. And you have much more control over the valves in order to create the functionality you need.

Comment: Thank you..., tried this:  tank, two outflows, outflow 1 just circulates at 1 m3/s back to inlet (so set the delay time at number of m3 = sec).  The circulating flow simulates the "settling time"; when that completes it opens the other outflow.  Then created a function that will close the circulating outflow and open the inflow again (acts as an interrupt).  Works great!  Thanks for this tip...